# SetTimeout for fusion charts

Tags: jquery, charts, fusioncharts

How to SetTimeout for fusion charts to make the chart load with a few minutes delay?

```
var myChart= new FusionCharts( {"../FusionCharts/MSLine.swf", "Chart",  "100%", "32%", "0", "1");
myChart.setXMLData("chart1.xml");    
FusionCharts.setCurrentRenderer('javascript');  
myChart.render("Chart");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :-

```
function mycharts()
{
   var myChart= new FusionCharts( {"../FusionCharts/MSLine.swf", "Chart",  "100%", "32%", "0", "1");
   myChart.setXMLData("chart1.xml");    
   FusionCharts.setCurrentRenderer('javascript');  
   myChart.render("Chart"); 
}

setTimeout(function(){ mycharts() }, 3000);
```

Comment: what should i pass to myChart().. I tried this already like this: window.setTimeout(function () {
                   var myChart= new FusionCharts( {"../FusionCharts/MSLine.swf", "Chart",  "100%", "32%", "0", "1");
myChart.setXMLData("chart1.xml");    
FusionCharts.setCurrentRenderer('javascript');  
myChart.render("Chart"); 
 
}, 5000);

Comment: Can u tell me exactly where should I place this line in the code that i have given? Because its giving me exception and am not sure.

Comment: I tried this: window.setTimeout(function () {
                    var myChart = new FusionCharts("../FusionCharts/MSLine.swf", "SLACompliancelineChart", "100%", "32%", "0", "1");
                    myChart.setXMLData(data.d); //retrieving xml chart data
                    FusionCharts.setCurrentRenderer('javascript');
                    myChart.render("SLAComplianceline"); //rendering the chart data using div id
 
                }, 5000);                                                                and the chart is not loading.. The div in which the chart is, its just empty

Comment: JavaScript runtime error: A FusionChart oject with the specified id "SLACompliancelineChart" already exists. Renaming it to chartobject-1     ------- This is the error that am getting when I run the project.

Comment: @user3564495... http://forum.fusioncharts.com/topic/8468-a-fusionchart-oject-with-the-specified-id-mychartid-already-exists/

Comment: I checked the forum and in that I found out that AJAX does not execute the script tag within it so that stops the chart from rendering. So, I need to call the dispose() at the onclick event of my next button. I tried adding "onClick="FusionCharts('SLACompliancelineChart').dispose();" to the next button after which my chart will be shown. Its not working. Can u guide me the proper way? Also, there are more than one chart in the page when I click on the next button.

Comment: @user3564495..i use google charts and i do this way only with settimeout it will call specified function again and again after specified time interval there is no problem with above answer..its a problem of fusion charts only..i just try to help you at the best of my knowledge,,thanks...

Comment: @n-bhargav.. The settimeout function seems to be working but immediately after few seconds am getting the error which I mentioned above:"A FusionChart oject with the specified id "SLACompliancelineChart" already exists". For this I need to call the dispose() at onclick but the variable's scope is limited only within the function so am not able to call the dispose() at onclick.